# Get value of option attribute with option_id

Tags: magento

I have an attribute "account_status" of option type. It has two value "valid" and "invalid".  I am trying to get its value using below code :

```
$customer->getAccountStatus(); //o/p is 10 i.e. option_id in eav_attribute_option table
```

But I want value from eav_attribute_option_value table.

How can I get this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get value of an option attrbute for `$customer` Model

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')
    ->getAttribute('account_status')
    ->getSource()->getOptionText($customer->getAccountStatus());
```

In your own answer you have provided way to get all options for an attribute. You can get in this way as well

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')
        ->getAttribute('account_status')
        ->getSource()
        ->getAllOptions();
```

To get option Id for a option value

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')
        ->getAttribute('account_status')
        ->getSource()
        ->getOptionId('my_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and it is working..

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'account_status'); // "gender" is attribute_code
      $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
      foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
      $genders[$instance['value']] = $instance['label'];
}
```

Is this the standard way to access option attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

Here easy to get all attribute options here

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');     
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
              ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
              ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code','attribute name');

$_attribute = $collection->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
$attribute_options  = $_attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
print_r($attribute_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to below code for get customer address attribute dropdown values. (My Attribute name : address_name)

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) 
{
$addressesCollection = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
foreach ($addressesCollection->getAddresses() as $addresses) 
{
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addresses->getId());
$attr = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getResource()->getAttribute('address_name');
if ($attr->usesSource()) 
{
$address_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($address->getAddressName());
}
}
}
?>
```